# mostrar resultados en DIV o SPAN

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

quisiera que el resultado en vez de que salga en console.log saliera en varios DIV o SPAN por ejemplo
---div Id="div1">resultado uno------div Id="div2">resultado dos------div Id="div3">resultado tres----div Id="div4">resultado cuatro---

aqui dejo el codigo en js

```
           function Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos(){
           const Horario = {
           dia: {
           inicio: 8,
           fin: 13
           },
           tarde: {
           inicio: 16,
           fin: 20
           },
           cada: 15,
          };
        var now = new Date();
        var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 
        now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
        var final  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 
        Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);
        for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + 
        Horario.cada))
        {
        let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para dar 
        formato de 2 digitos
        let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
        console.log(hora + ":" + minutos );
        }
        }
```

Comment: En el HTML necesitas un contenedor (`div` u otro) al que agregues el contenido que obtendrás al leer el bucle.

Comment: intento con ciclo for y no me sale

Comment: var i = hora
    for (i=1;i<=fin;i++) { 
      document.getElementById("<span" + i + ">Encabezado de nivel " + i + "</span" + i + ">") 
     
 }

Comment: `document.getElementById` debe ser usado para alcanzar un elemento por su ID, y por lógica ese documento debe existir previamente. No lo estás usando correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitarías tener un contenedor previamente identificado al cual agregarás posteriormente los elementos una vez creados. Yo he creado en el HTML este elemento: `<div id="resultados"></div>` y lo usaré para poner en él los diferentes elementos que se vayan creando.

Te mostraré una forma **segura y optimizada** de hacerlo.

Con respecto a la **seguridad**, sin duda encontrarás código que agregaría el contenido usando cosas como `innerHTML`, lo cual **no es seguro**, debido a los riesgos de inyección de código, por eso he creado los elementos con `createElement()` y he seteado sus atributos y su contenido con funciones dedicadas a esos fines.

Con respecto a la optimización, la web está plagada de malos ejemplos en los cuales, para casos como estos, sugieren agregar cada elemento al `div` contenedor dentro del mismo bucle, lo cual **no es óptimo**, porque no conviene modificar el DOM dentro de bucles. Por eso he usado un fragmento, he agregado todo a ese fragmento dentro del bucle y finalmente he agregado ese fragmento al div contenedor una vez el bucle haya terminado, así, el DOM se modificará una sola vez. Esta es la forma más óptima, porque **cada vez que modificas el DOM, éste se renderiza**. Si tu bucle tiene `N` elementos y modificas el DOM `N` veces, significa que el DOM se renderizará `N` veces y eso puede terminar siendo muy costoso.

Veamos el código. He puesto comentarios para que se entienda mejor. He usado un elemento `p` por parecerme el más adecuado. Pero lo puedes cambiar por un `span`, por un `div` o por lo que quieras. En ese caso, te aconsejo que los espacios entre líneas los gestiones mediante reglas de estilo en un archivo `.css`, aplicando así el principio de separación de responsabilidades.

Si hay algo que no has entendido, me lo puedes decir en un comentario, al pie de esta respuesta. Espero te sirva.

```js
Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos();

function Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos() {
  /*Referencia al div contenedor general*/
  mDiv = document.getElementById('resultados');
  /*Fragmento para ir agregando cada elemento*/
  var mFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


  const Horario = {
    dia: {
      inicio: 8,
      fin: 13
    },
    tarde: {
      inicio: 16,
      fin: 20
    },
    cada: 15,
  };
  var now = new Date();
  var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),
    now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
  var final = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(),
    Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);
  /*Variable para identificar cada id de los p*/
  var i = 1;
  for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() +
      Horario.cada)) {
    let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para dar formato de 2 digitos
    let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    /*Creamos un elemento p*/
    var mP = document.createElement("p");
    /*Establecemos su id con el valor de i y aumentamos i en 1*/
    mP.setAttribute("id", `p${i++}`);
    //console.log(mP);
    /*Le agregamos el contenido de forma segura*/
    mP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${hora}:${minutos}`));
    /*Lo agregamos al fragmento*/
    mFragment.appendChild(mP);
    //console.log(hora + ":" + minutos);
  }
  /*Finalmente, agregamos el fragmento al div contenedor*/
  mDiv.appendChild(mFragment);
}
```

```html
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente explicacion, me sirvió y anda perfecto...muchas gracias por tu valioso tiempo solucionando.

Comment: si quiero poner variables que se tomen de otros DIV en los horarios por ejemplo de 8 a 12 yo los tengo en unos div, cómo irían const Horario = {
    dia: {
      inicio: div1,
      fin: div2
    },
    tarde: {
      inicio: div3,
      fin: div4
    },
    cada: div5,
  };

Comment: @JulioAndres no entendí tu pregunta. Cualquier cosa que exista previamente la puedes obtener usando `document.getElementById`, de modo que si tienes algo en un `div` y quieres obtener esa información, alcanzarías ese `div` por su id y recogerías lo que hay en él. Cabe decir que hay otras formas de guardar información, como los atributos `data-` por ejemplo. Sea como sea, si tienes una duda nueva puedes abrir una nueva pregunta, aunque se refiera al mismo problema. Ten en cuenta que SO funciona por preguntas.

Comment: infinitas gracias @A. Cedano